# Add caption or helper text to admin filter in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, filter

I added a filter in my admin panel. But i want to add a helper text before or after the input field.

Like the 'more information about...' in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot with more info as helper text]

Right now the field config I have is below, but neither caption or placeholder are showing:
I can't find any config options for adding a filter like this. Is this possible?

```
<column name="country_id" class="IWD\StoreLocator\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Country">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">US, GB, BE, FR ...</item>
                    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">US, GB, BE, FR ...</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```